# CSS - Text to move up on load

Tags: css

On my page load I'm trying to get text to move up and fade in on page load.

(Example here: https://fabriceleven.com/design/creating-fancy-css3-fade-in-animations-on-page-load/)

I've got the fade in working fine, however when I try the code below for the moveUp animation, the text doesn't appear at all. Where am i going wrong?

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
  opacity:0;  
  -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1; 
  -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
  animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; 
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;

  -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1s;
  animation-duration:1s;
}

@keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
      transform: translate(0px,20px);
  }
  100% {
      transform: translate(0px,0px);
  }
}

.move-up {
  animation:moveUp ease-in 1;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-duration:1s;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<h1 class="paddingTop20 fade-in move-up">Leading Topic</h1>
```

Comment: FWIW, I see the text but there's no animation.

Comment: At the top of the page, if you refresh, the text 'creating fancy css3...' animation is on that

Comment: Your animation would move the element _down_ not up.

Comment: I meant with the CSS you provided here, not the example link.

Comment: The y is -50px at 0%, and 0px at 100%, wouldn't that move it up?

Comment: No. https://jsfiddle.net/do1wtodp/1/ Coordinates are based top-left to bottom-right

Comment: On that page, the text is moving up right?

Comment: In Turnip's fiddle, it's moving down from the top. (Did you not mean to make the first value negative? 0px is the very top of the page so -50 is above that.)

Comment: I can't adjust that - in that JDFiddle it works, but on my side, when I apply the class `move-up` to the text - the text doesn't even appear. Any ideas?

Comment: Please include all code necessary to reproduce your problem in the question itself, as a [mcve]. Currently, there is no HTML in the question.

Comment: Updated with code

Comment: check [this](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) out, its a whole lot of css3 animations, just take what you need. It's been around for a long time & works. Also you may need to add a transition delay so it gives time for the page to load, [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay).

Comment: Problem with my code was in the HTML I was applying the 2 animations with separate CSS classes. They had to be in one

Answer (score 0):

This can be best achieved with javascript. Something along the line of this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <title>Happy rising text</title>

   <style type="text/css">
       #yourHtmlTag{
           text-align: center;

           /*This is needed.*/
           position: absolute;
           top: 30%;
           transition: all 1s ease-out;
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="floatUp()">
   <header id="yourHtmlTag">Float Up!</header>

<!-- The script needs to be below where it is called -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   function floatUp(){
       document.getElementById('yourHtmlTag').style.top = "15%";
   }
</script>
</body>
```

This has been tested, if you have any other questions don't hesitate to ask!